Fair comparison method for a biased physics-based model and its ML-correction version
I'm working with two prediction models:

A calibrated physics-based model that consistently overestimates and has a fixed bias.
An XGBoost model that predicts the error of the physics model to create corrected predictions. (The dataset contains the physics model's predictions and the target variable. We then predict the error between the target variable and the physical models prediction)

I'm trying to fairly compare these models, but I'm unsure about the best approach. Simply using MAPE for both doesn't seem meaningful due to the known bias in the physics model.
Here's what I'm considering:
For the physics model:

Calculate errors: errors = physics_model_prediction - actual_value
Compute mean error: mean_error = errors.mean()
Adjust errors: adjusted_errors = errors - mean_error
Calculate MAPE: MAPE(adjusted_errors, actual_value)

For the corrected model:

Calculate MAPE(corrected_prediction, actual_value)

Is this approach valid? The residuals' distribution in the correction model is slightly skewed but close to normal, tending to overestimate at certain values. But I'm wondering if this method is statistically sound. If there are better ways to compare the improvements I would appreciate any insights!




Usually Physics guidance is applied to ML models, not the other way around. Only meaningful comparison in this context is how physics guidance improve the baseline ML model.

From your description it seems that the two models do not do the same thing - XGBoost is applied to the predictions already made by the physics model... it is a bit the apples and the oranges. One could perhaps compare physics model with physics model + XGBoost... but I won't speculate further.

Hey, thank you for the comments. The problem is the physics-based model gives around 25-30% MAPE, while the correction model gives around 7-8% MAPE for the same data that was reserved to evaluate the generalizability. So I'm just wondering if it makes sense to compare these two values to each other when we know that the physics-based model always overestimates x amount. To get more fair comparison I was thinking if taking the mean out of the distribution would yield more fair results, then we would be talking about 11% mape to around 7%.

Please tag the person that you are responding to - like @menzerml  - otherwise, they are not aware of your comment, unless they look for it specifically). Your physics model takes data and predicts something ($X\rightarrow Y$), whereas your XGBoost model takes the results of the physics model and predicts something else ($Y\rightarrow Z$). Understanding which values you are comparing is possibly the key to your problem. If you add some visuals it could be helpful (like distributions of errors arising from the two models - how many data points do you have btw?)

@RogerV
Thank you for your feedback. I have added the plots as you suggested. To clarify the process, the physics-based model takes input data (X) and predicts an intermediate result (Y), but it does not account for certain influential factors necessary for accurately predicting Y. The XGBoost model then takes the intermediate result (Y) along with additional influential data to predict an adjustment (Z). I am comparing the intermediate result (Y) with the final adjusted prediction (Y + Z). I hope this clarifies the process.

Do you correct every measurement? It seems strange that your standard deviation for error corrected results is the same as for the uncorrected ones, even though the correct has its own error. The fact that you work directly with residuals hides how exactly the correction is applied. Perhaps one could see something in a scatterplot of uncorrected and corrected data points vs. the actual data. Also, a scatterplot of the corrected vs uncorrected data could be interesting - to see whether correction is applied uniformly. Disclaimer: I am not a statistician, but a physicist and bioinformatician.

It seems like you don’t want to penalize the physics-based model for being biased. Why?

@RogerV.
Sorry if the plots were not clear,
The first plot shows the distribution for the error correction model, which takes into account the physics-based model's predictions and then corrects the errors.
The second plot shows the distribution for the physics-based model itself.
The third plot displays the results after making the adjustments mentioned in the post, specifically subtracting the mean for the physics-based model (no error correction). Which is why it has the same std.

The plots are clear - I am just saying that working with the residuals hides certain things, which could be seen, if making scatterplots for the actual values. Also, if bias is just a number, same for all data points, there is no much to explore - you simply shift the curve. I don't know if it makes sense in your particular physical context - your correction does not depend on the result of the measurement, parameters, etc.

Since the comments are getting crowded, I'm creating an answer instead, but these are mostly small remarks.

What's the goal of the comparison?

it's unclear to me why we are comparing the methods, and I'm not sure if it's clearer for you
if the goal is to show that correcting somehow the bias of the physics model, then we don't need to correct it the bias when computing the metric
if the goal is to show that the xgboost is better than a simple rescaling correction, then we should first compute the performance of a rescaling correction


Best correction for the MAPE

your suggested correction is to offset all predictions by the absolute error

that's a decent choice, but not fully appropriate for MAPE

if I'm absolutely nitpicking, this would be correct to optimize the mean-squared error; it's not correct for absolute error instead of squared (shift by the median instead)  or for relative error (shift the value after the ratio)

try this instead. Let $x$ be the true value, $y$ the prediction:
$$
    \begin{align}
    \text{absolute error } &= y - x \\
    \text{relative error } &= \frac{y - x}{x} \\
    \text{median bias } = b &= \mathrm{median}\frac{y - x}{x} \\
    \text{corrected estimate } &= (1 - b)y
    \end{align}
    $$
Note that we could use the value of $x$ in correcting, but that feels like cheating



Reading your description, I'm worried about double-dipping: using the data both to fit and to compute the performance metric.

if you use the same data to train the ML algorithm and compute the MAPE, you will have lower MAPE then it's actual performance would be on new data
make sure you use two separate datasets
technically, the same remark applies for correcting the bias of the physics model, but it matters less with a single parameter


Is your XGBoost model using only the value of the physics prediction?

that's an extremely small amount of information
the only thing it could learn would be to correct the value depending on the absolute value of the transformation
to investigate this, it seems appropriate to do a scatter plot of the true value, physics prediction, corrected physics prediction, XGBoost prediction




Thank you for the comprehensive answer, I will reply in parts due to the character limit.
Part 1)
(1) We have a physical model that predicts the target variable X using equations based on known physical phenomena. However, it does not perform well in diverse settings.
(2) We have a machine learning model that incorporates real-world data and domain knowledge to predict the error of the physical model (model 1). It then adjusts the final predictions by adding the predicted error to the output of model 1.

Part2)
I wanted to compare the performance of the physical model (model 1) and the machine learning model (model 2) for one of my experiments. However, simply looking at the error metrics didn't seem sufficient, especially since we know that the physical model is always systematically biased.
You were worried about the data leakage. The first 90% of the data is used for training and validation through time series cross-validation, given the sequential nature of our data. The remaining 10% is set aside and only used for the final evaluation of the model to evaluate its generalizability.

Thank you for the proposed method in your second point I will look into this.

Given your comprehensive answer, it seems like you are doing the right thing. You are giving rich-data to your model to smartly correct the bias. I would advise you to compare the performance of the ML-bias correction to both the uncorrected model and a dumb-correction. I would also advise you to plot the scatter-plot of real-value and the various estimates. Bon courage.
